# Как достать тег по касанию объекта Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
    if (true)
    {
        var ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(1).position);

        RaycastHit hitInfo;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo))
        {
            var rig = hitInfo.collider.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            if (rig != null)
            {
                var bb = hitInfo.collider.GetComponent<GameObject>();
                b = bb.tag; //в переменную б нужно передать значение тега объекта который касаемся
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Все, разобрался.
`rig.gameObject.tag` - так можно обратиться к тегу объекта на который нажму.